# responseText of Ajax (XMLHttpRequest) request is undefined

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have been trying my hands on a simple console app which will do two things.
(1.) It will make an asynchronous Ajax request.
(2.) log the responseText to the console.

To go about this,i made my ajax request to openweathermap.org and tried to parse the responseText to JSON and finally log it to the console.

Please find below my code to achieve this

```
var data ;
var url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=7535661&APPID=56104080d6cb412468dad1627cb27da6";

var myRequest;

function sendRequest(url){
    myRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    myRequest.onreadystatechange= function(){
    if(myRequest.readyState == 4 && myRequest.status== 200){
       data= JSON.parse(myRequest.responseText);

    }
   myRequest.open("GET", url, true );
   myRequest.send();
    }
   console.log(data);
   }

sendRequest(url);
```

Each time i try running this, it is always returing "undefined".

Please help me out.

Answer (score 2):

You have your `open()` and `send()` methods inside your `onreadystatechange()` callback. So, you're never opening the connection, unless the request completes. Try this:

```
var data;
var url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=7535661&APPID=56104080d6cb412468dad1627cb27da6";

var myRequest;

function sendRequest(url) {
  myRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
  myRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (myRequest.readyState == 4 && myRequest.status == 200) {
      data = JSON.parse(myRequest.responseText);
      console.log(data);
    }
  }
  myRequest.open("GET", url, true);
  myRequest.send();
}

sendRequest(url);
```

Comment: I don't get undefined, but the actual information shown as an object in the console, see this: http://jsfiddle.net/1xn7dt6k/2/

Keep in mind that this endpoint you're hitting isn't a secure endpoint (HTTP), so you won't be able to make that request if you're serving this code from an HTTPS page, without mixed-content enabled.

Comment: Thanks Cint, i will put that to test and give a feedback.

Comment: Yea, my request is being served from an HTTPS page. I amusing  repl.it to compile my code. I have tried to enable mixed content but i haven't been  able to do so. Its getting me frustrated..